# How to pass context from activity to activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I have a main activity, and it summons another activity to display some data.

I have a private database helper object that I use throughout the main activity code. Is there a way to pass the context of my main activity to my sub activity in an elegant way? (ie, from subclass, something like `getCallingActivityContext()`)

I could always create new database helper objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extending the Application class helps you to allow declare/access global variables. You can set your variables from any activity to `ApplicationContext` and access it from other activity without using bundle.

[How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables) will help you.

Answer (score 4):

For your case, I would recommend you to extend instead the [Application class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html). All your activities have access to the Application context by calling [getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29) at any time.
Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables/708317#708317) the 1st answer for an example.

Comment: You would be better linking to [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables/708317#708317) rather than the question